# Laravel Admin route not working but others are

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with my Laravel project. I created an admin route group (domain.co/admin/). The root `/admin/` at one point was working then i added a few more pages have updated composer, installed doctrine/dbal, and installed chart.js since then. Now for some reason the `/admin/` route no longer works but all other routes work perfectly normal.

my web.php routes look like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Auth::routes(); // tried commenting this out

Route::middleware(['web','auth','rolecheck:Super'])->prefix('admin')- 
    >group(function(){
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
        Route::get('/test', 'AdminController@index');
        Route::get('/test2', 'AdminController@test');
    ....
});

...
```

There are more route groups that also work

`/admin/` gives me a permission error. `/admin/test/` `/admin/test2/` work fine

here is the controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        echo '2';
        //return view('admin.dashboard');
    }

    public function test(){
        echo '1';
    }

}
```

.htaccess doesnt show anything weird (default from laravel). I have also tried clearing caches.

I found nothing in the /etc/httpd conf files.

I have tired looking through all the code for the word 'admin' and can't find anything that is pointing to why its saying permission denied.

If i change the prefix to 'admins' it works so i am guessing some part of laravel is blocking the admin/ route. Where else can i look to see where its being blocked.

Answer (score 7):

Check your public folder if you have 'admin' folder there, then rename it. In my case it was a reason of such a behavior.[folders structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Oli6.png)

Comment: It's a very funny issue. =)

Answer (score 0):

Check the config/auth file in your laravel directory and check the guards and providers array in it default look like this.

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
```

Comment: mine looks like this 
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],  
there is nothing that says admin

Answer (score 0):

Copy/Paste these files (**.htaccess, index.php, favicon.ico, robots.txt**) from the `/public` folder  to the `/public/admin` folder.

Edit the `/public/admin/index.php` file and add "/.." to all 3 required php files:

from

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
```